# 1/4" Reverse Osmosis Filter inlet line to undersink cold water line

Tags: plumbing, valve, kitchen-sink, shutoff

I am trying to connect an under counter Reverse Osmosis ( R.O. ) filter inlet line (*red 1/4" tubing*) to the cold water supply line (*3/8" black tubing in picture*) under my kitchen sink.

Can anyone help me figure out what sort of Tee/adapter fitting I need to get this done?

Obviously I still need the black cold water supply line to feed the sink faucet as well as this red R.O. Filter inlet line.

I also want the shut-off valve to be in the line to the R.O. filter.

Thanks!

enter image description here

[image: RO inlet]

Additional pictures here showing sizes of connections: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuXhV.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze4gc.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7nlz.jpg

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a tee that has two females and one male. The typical size for this situation is 3/8" or 1/2", you note that you have 3/8"

Use Teflon tape on the threads too.

Note that one of the images below is 2M1F but is otherwise visually representative of what you need

[image]
[image]

Comment: Don't use teflon tape on compression fittings or fittings that have an O-ring. Those seal in other ways. Most connectors of this type will be one of those 2, so most likely no need for teflon tape in this case.