# What size pipe fitting has an outside diameter of about 1/2 inch?

Tags: plumbing

So in another thread this week I [asked a question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/188647/1-4-reverse-osmosis-filter-inlet-line-to-undersink-cold-water-line) about the type of valve I need but I ordered the wrong size...uggh.

I ordered [this tee connection](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07XK87ZLV) because it included a shut off valve...which I like.

The new valve thread (3/8") is too big for the existing nut.
Can someone help me confirm the correct size I need this time?

Half inch (see photo) minus 1/4" for threads = 1/4"...?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1/4" NPT fittings have a nominal outside diameter of just over .5". That's what you have.

Comment: 3/8 and 1/4 are your only real options so I would say Isherwood is right. Since 3/8 did not fit.

Answer (score 1):

That brass fitting you are measuring is not a tee but looks like a compression fitting. If it is a compression fitting a pipe fitting will not screw onto it. A better explanation and a better picture of what you are trying to accomplish is needed.